# Image with height:auto ends up with computed height of zero

Tags: html, css

I'm stumped as to why the site logo is not displaying on this site:

http://www.rainbowwings.org

Ideally I'd like the logo to float left, the site name to display slightly offset to the right of the logo, and the nav links to float right.  No matter what I've tried, however, the logo ends up 0 height and doesn't display at all (yes, it exists on the site).

Any ideas on how to fix the CSS to style these 3 elements correctly?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Firstly, `<img href="/images/FlyingOrigami_03.png">` should be `<img src="/images/FlyingOrigami_03.png">` using the `src` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `<img href"">` instead of the correct image tag using `<img src="">`. In your case, you should change this to:

```
<img src="/images/FlyingOrigami_03.png">
```

Read more about how to use the `<img>` element on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img).

Of course, you'll then need to get rid of extraneous CSS rules, such as: `img.site-headerimg { width: 100%; }`, which will stretch the logo out to the full width of your screen.

Comment: Thanks, it's been a while since I've written HTML, time to pull HTML Lint back out of the toolkit :-/